# Space of finite signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, total-variation, signed-measures

Given a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, let $\nu$ be a signed measure on that space and let $|\nu| := \nu^+ + \nu^-$ be the variation.
Now consider the measurable functions $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and collect all of them in a space we call $F$, i.e.,
$$F:= \{X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Let $V$ be the space of all finite signed measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$. Now consider the space $$K:=\{\nu\in V:\int_{\Omega}|X(\omega)|d|\nu|<\infty\}.$$

1.) Now, can there any intuition be gained about the signed measures in this space? E.g., what does it tell me to integrate with respect to the variation of a signed measure? Why not just integrate with respect to just the signed measure?

2.) Also it looks kind of similar to the definition of $L^p$ spaces. Is there any connection to them?

Next, consider the Hahn-Decomposition $\nu = \rho + \sigma$, such that $\rho$ is absolutely continuous to some measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$. That is, $\rho$ has a density w.r.t. $\mu$. Let us now define the space
$$R:=\{\nu\in V:\int_{\Omega}|X(\omega)|d|\rho|<\infty\}.$$

I am reading some lecture notes where it is stated that now each $\nu \in R$ can be identified with the density of $\rho$ w.r.t. $\mu$.

3.) What exactly does that mean and why can we do that? Is there some bijection?

It is also stated that these densities of $\rho$ w.r.t. $\mu$ are in $L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ if our $X$ are in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Furthermore, it is being said that the pairing on $F\times V$, where $V$ is the vector space of all finite signed measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, given by $\langle X, \nu \rangle=\int X dv$, this pairing comes down to the usual pairing between $L^p$ and $L^q$, i.e., for $f\in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$ we have
$\langle f, g \rangle=\int f g d\mu$.

4.) Is there an obvious way to see that?

5.) Does that mean that the space $R$ is the dual space of $L^p$?

Comment: What lecture notes are you reading?

Comment: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK4400/h18/notater/riskmeasuresduality(1).pdf

Comment: first paragraph of section 3.3

Comment: Looking at your lecture notes it seems that $F$ should be *some* vector space of measurable functions, not necessarily the space of *all* measurable functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions.

1. I think the best way to think about $K$ is as the space of those signed measures $\nu$ which can be made into linear functionals on $F$ as
   $$\label{1} X \mapsto \int_\Omega X \, d\nu. \tag{1}$$
   If you think about it this way, then it is clear why we need to define $K$ the way it is as we need
   $$\int_\Omega |X| \, d|\nu| < \infty$$
   to make sense of the integral in \eqref{1}.
2. One of the connections to $L^p$-spaces is the example given in your lecture notes (which I gather your remaining questions are about).

Reading your lecture notes I gather that in the remaining questions we set $F = L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ for some fixed measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$.

3. I guess the point of introducing $R$ here is that $K$ is quite unnatural in this case.
   The reason being my answer to question 1 that we should think of $K$ as a space of linear functionals on $F$.
   The problem here is that $L^p$ is not a space of measurable functions but a space of equivalence classes of measurable functions, where two functions are equivalent if they agree on a $\mu$-null set.
   Hence if $\nu$ is a measure which is singular to $\mu$, then there is no way to make sense of \eqref{1}.
   I therefore think that $R$ should be defined a bit differently, namely as those elements of $K$ which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.
   It is then clear how to identify $R$ with the space of densities by using the Radon-Nikodym theorem, and it is clear that $R$ is the subspace of $K$ which are well-defined linear functionals on $L^p$.
4. To show that the density of $\rho$ is in $L^q$ for $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ you can use the same techniques as one uses to show that the dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$.
   For the second part, if $M$ is the density of $\rho$, then for any $X \in L^p$ we have
   $$\int_\Omega X \, d\rho = \int_\Omega XM \, d\mu = \langle X, M \rangle$$
   by the Radon-Nikodym theorem.
5. $R$ is not necessarily the dual of $L^p$ since we only consider finite signed measures.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I still dont understand regarding question (1) why we integrate with respect to the total variation measure instead of just the measure.
Also regarding your answer to question 4, an important point to that question is that Lq is not actually the dual space of Lp.
Regarding answer to 5): What would be missing to make it the dual of Lp?

Comment: And also why do we even look at signed measures here in the first place? Why are (non-negative) measures not sufficient here?

Comment: 1) How would you define the integral with respect to the signed measure? 4) Why is $L^q$ not the dual of $L^p?$ 5) For $f \in L^q$ it is not necessarily the case that $f \, d \mu$ is a finite measure. In that case $f \, d \mu \notin R$. If you do not look at signed measures you will not get a vector space. If $\nu$ is a non-trivial positive measure, then $- \nu$ is not a positive measure.

Comment: Re 1) So my question has always been why we integrate w.r.t. the total variation measure i.e. $d|\mu|$ instead of w.r.t $d\mu$? Re 4) $L^q$ consists of functions $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that fulfill certain bounded conditions. However, the dual of $L^p$ consists of functions $f:L^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. There is of course an isometric isomorphism between the dual of $L^p$ and $L^q$, but $L^q$ is not the dual.

Comment: 1) Because we have to. Like I said, how would you even integrate against the signed measure unless you know $X$ is integrable with respect to the total variation measure? 4) This is what is meant when one says $L^q$ is the dual of $L^p$.

Comment: I mean I dont know, but I was hoping to get an answer here. I dont know why we should not be able to integrate against the signed measure if X is not integrable w.r.t. to the total variation measure. I have never seen such a requirement in a text book or so...

Comment: The usual definition for positive $X$ is $\int X \, d \nu = \int X \, d \nu^+ - \int X \, d \nu^-$. You will then run into trouble if both $ \int X \, d \nu^+ = \infty$ and $\int X \, d \nu^- = \infty$.

Comment: but then i could just simply require that $\int X d \nu < \infty$ holds instead of $\int X d |\nu| < \infty$. And thats what I dont understand here.

Comment: The expression $\int X \, d \nu < \infty$ makes no sense before you define the left hand side, and I just showed you why the left hand side is not always well-defined. However the assumption $\int X \, d |\nu| < \infty$ makes it so that we **can** define what $\int X \, d \nu$ means.

Comment: But if $\int X d\nu$ is not well defined then also $\int X d|\nu|$ is not well defined because they both are constructed via the terms $\int X d\nu^+$ and $\int X d\nu^-$. One by subtraction of these terms and the other by addition of these terms

Comment: Since $\int X \, d|\nu| = \int X \, d\nu^+ + \int X \, d \nu^-$ this is well defined as we won't get the problem with $\infty - \infty$. Addition with terms in $[0, \infty]$ is unproblematic, the problem is subtraction.